# How do I check multiple permissions at the same time on facebook connect?

Tags: facebook

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('status_update,offline_access', function(perms) 
{
if(!perms) 
  return callback(false);  
else 
 return callback(true);
});
```

How do I check multiple permissions at the same time? The above code works only for status_update and its not checking offline access.

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark, maybe `['status_update', 'offline_access']` instead of `'status_update,offline_access'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL, which is generally preferred for retrieving FB data with the least overhead.

```
SELECT publish_stream, offline_access, email 
    from permissions where uid = FBUserid
```